# Two unique columns (unique for any order) postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have a table which links together two identifiers. I want these to be unique, i.e.:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1) <----- invalid, violates 1,2
```

I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE identifiers_relationships (
    id serial primary key,
    identifier1_id integer,
    identifier2_id integer,

    check (
        identifier1_id != identifier2_id
    )
);

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE identifiers_relationships_duplicate_rule AS 
    ON INSERT TO identifiers_relationships 
    WHERE EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM identifiers_relationships WHERE
        /* basically check for (a, b) already existing) */
        (identifier1_id = NEW.identifier1_id AND identifier2_id = NEW.identifier2_id)
        OR
        /* OR check if (b, a) exists */
        (identifier1_id = NEW.identifier2_id AND identifier2_id = NEW.identifier1_id)
    )
    DO NOTHING;
```

But then it still lets me do this:

```
db=> select * from identifiers_relationships;
 id | identifier1_id | identifier2_id 
----+----------------+----------------
  1 |              2 |              1
  2 |              1 |              2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: You should ask only one question at a time.  I would suggest you remove the "bonus" question from this and ask it as another question.

Comment: Thnk you Gordon I have done just that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487312/propagate-set-pairs-to-child-pairs-on-insertion-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making the first identifier *less* than the second and putting a unique constraint on the two values:

```
CREATE TABLE identifiers_relationships (
    id serial primary key,
    identifier1_id integer,
    identifier2_id integer,

    check (identifier1_id < identifier2_id),
    unique (identifier1_id, identifier2_id)
);
```

You can use `<=` if you want to allow equality.

Comment: How can I easily have the database switch the identifiers if they are inserted in a non-less manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function based index on:

```
create index unq_identifiers_relationships 
on identifiers_relationships (   least(identifier1_id,identifier2_id),
                              greatest(identifier1_id,identifier2_id));
```

... and that will prevent the insertion of (1,2) if (2,1) is already present.