# Propagate new set pairs to all children pairs in a table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, triggers

I have a table which is similar to the following:

`serial, integer1, integer2`

There is constraint that `integer1 != integer2`, and the sets `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` cannot coexist (because they are the same set, in a different order).

Is there an easy way so that I can do the following:

When ever I insert an identifier pair, it will propagate the relationship down to all of each identifier's other pairs.  For instance:

Start with:

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
```

If I insert `(1, 3)`; automatically make `(1, 4)` `(2, 4)` and `(2, 3)`.  Would be nice if there is some select trickery that can be performed, but I think it will probably need to be a trigger to actually physically create those rows. Any suggestions for the best way to do this?

I want this to be ultra recursive.

Comment: Couple of questions. Q1: `Start with:` mean you table have 2 rows? Q2: `automatically make` mean create all pair using the available integers between min and max values already in your table? I see what you do, but not sure if could make a general rule good enought to work with a different sample set. Maybe aditional example will help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd say the best option is to create a table **group**, and a table **serial**. The group table would be where you say *integer 1 and 2 are part of the group A* and *integer 2, 3, and 4 are part of the group B*. The serial table would be a list of all "coordinates" within a group and the associated serial.

From there, you can make a trigger on your group table when inserting, deleting and updating, where you propagate the changes to your **serial** table (either disable the now extinct coordinates or delete them, and then create new entries with a *null* or default serial, could even be generated through a stored procedure or a trigger on the **serial** table).

The reason that I would work with groups is because it allows you to manage deletion more easily. If you don't split the table, it's gonna be rough to remove 1 from the group A.

So basically :

- Table integer (if appropriate) : **Integer** + other valuable data
- Table group (a pseudo-junction table between integer and integer) : **Integer, Group**
- Table Serial (the actual junction table between integer and integer) : **Integer, Integer**, Serial + other valuable data. All inserts and removes should be done automatically by triggers on the table group.